# How to apply background color to View without giving any padding?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have already tried backgroundColor but for no success.

I have the following code and want to apply background color to the main parent View but dont want to specify any padding, how to acheive this?

```
<View style={{flex:1,alignItems:'center'}}>  
    <Text>
      No new Transactions
    </Text>
    <View style={{backgroundColor:'#fc004f',paddingTop:44,paddingBottom:40,top:56,borderRadius:8,width:window.width-20,borderWidth:2,borderColor:'#dddddd'}}>
        <Text style={{position:'absolute',fontSize:16,top:14,paddingLeft:16,color:'white',fontWeight:'bold'}}>Big Bazaar</Text>
        <Text style={{position:'absolute',fontSize:14,top:48,paddingLeft:16,color:'white',fontWeight:'bold'}}>View Receipt</Text>
    </View>
     <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'#401f80',padding:44,top:56,borderRadius:8,width:window.width-20,borderWidth:2,borderColor:'#dddddd',marginTop:10}}>
       <Text style={{position:'absolute',fontSize:16,top:14,paddingLeft:16,color:'white',fontWeight:'bold'}}>Zomato Inc</Text>
      <Text style={{position:'absolute',fontSize:14,top:48,paddingLeft:16,color:'white',fontWeight:'bold'}}>View Receipt</Text>
    </View>
     <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'#fc004f',padding:44,top:56,borderRadius:8,width:window.width-20,borderWidth:2,borderColor:'#dddddd',marginTop:10}}>
        <Text style={{position:'absolute',fontSize:16,top:14,paddingLeft:16,color:'white',fontWeight:'bold'}}>OLA Inc</Text>
        <Text style={{position:'absolute',fontSize:14,top:48,paddingLeft:16,color:'white',fontWeight:'bold'}}>View Receipt</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
```

Comment: Have you tried to apply `backgroundColor` to its style?

Comment: Yes I have tried that but to no success

Comment: That occurs due to its been overridden by the children elements.

Comment: I don't know if i understand correctly, you want to set a background color to your parent view without giving any padding, is that right?, if that is the case what you need to do is add the `backgroundColor` property to the `View` that contains all the views, that should work

Comment: @PravandanChand what is preventing you from applying the background color to the main parent view without specifying any padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove flex:1 from the children views, and add `backgroundColor` to the parent view. Hope this helps!

Comment: can you provide a screenshot please ?

Comment: Its a style issue related to the children views, try to remove all styles from children view like padding and top etc , i guess the children are covering the parent .

Comment: did that also, removed every single style element from style, still no result

Comment: A screenshot of the output on the simulator or screenshot from the phone and not the code

Comment: Give the parent flex:1

Comment: tried that also, can you give me an example of giving a background color to the parent?

Comment: Just like you did, but i don't think the problem is here. Can you try to return any text and see if it shows ?

Comment: @PravandanChand Anytime!